# How to calculate the complexity of time and memory

Tags: math, big-o

I have the following code

```
public int X(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (X(n- 1) + X(n- 2));
}
```

I want to calculate the complexity of time and memory of this code

My code consists of a constant checking `if (n == 0) return 0;` so this will take a constant time assume `c` so we have either `c or c` or the calculation of the recursion functions which I can't calculate

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13055/time-complexity-and-space-complexity-in-recursive-algorithm

Comment: time complexity is exponential, space complexity is linear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the value of `X(n)`, you are calculating `X(n-1)` and `X(n-2)`

```
   So T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2);

      T(0) = 1
      T(1) = 1
```

which is exponential `O(2^n)`

If you want detailed proof of how it will be `O(2^n)`, check [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9899/why-does-a-recurrence-of-tn-1-tn-2-yield-something-in-omega2-fr).

Space complexity is linear.

(Just to be precise, If you consider the stack space taken for recursion, it's `O(n)`)